# Is it possible to port systemd services to sysVinit and vice versa? How much difficult it is.?

Tags: linux, systemd, system-v

I want to use `systemd` services on the system which is using `sysVinit`. Is it possible? Is any good way to do this.?

Answer (score 0):

An OS only has one init system at a time, so you can't run `systemd` services on a machine that not using `systemd` as the init system.

You can port the systemd "unit" files that control a service to the sysVinit style.

For common services, the easiest way to do this is to find an sysVinit file from a distribution that is already using sysVinit and then adapt it for your case.

Otherwise, look at some example `systemd` and `sysVinit` files. They are often that not complex, featuring the commands used to stop and start services and some other light configuration.

Comment: I am looking for more explanation to understand clearly